# Как сделать автоклик по объекту, с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Добрый день, не могу разобраться как сделать автоклик по объекту, с помощью javascript.

В данном случае по картинке , взял её в **div** и присвоил **id**. К картинке по клику привязано модальное окно, его и надо открыть.

```
<div id="ff1"><label for="modal-1"><img src="/uploads/main/bonus_ssi_ok.png"></label>/div>
```

Вот такую не красоту гуглил и пытался настроить, не работает. (вставлено в конце страницы)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#ff1').click(); 
    },5000);
    });
</script>

<script src="path/to/your/jquery.remodal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *К картинке по клику привязано модальное окно, его и надо открыть.* - к картинке или диву? как привязано?

Comment: картинку с двух сторон взял  <label>, и  уже этот <label> завернул в <div>

Comment: да это то видно, а вот обработчик клика совсем не очевиден. про это я и спрашивал

Comment: решил проблему! задал id именно изображению, всё работает. Спасибо автору, который отвечал в каком-то из здешних вопросов, оттуда взял скрипт.

Вопрос не актуален